# Большой, динамический фильтр SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10.

Необходимо реализовать фильтр выборки из таблицы по многим параметрам (пользовательский фильтр). 
Хоть весь список параметров нам известен, проблема в том что наперед неизвестно какие опции будут выбраны, еще одна проблема в том что, по некоторым полям, возможен множественный фильтр (IN, BETWEEN...) в этом случае параметром будет `List` или массив.

Как реализовать подобное?

**UPD:** Сейчас фильтра нету, просто загружается таблица в список

```
    public static List<Transaction> Transactions()
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DBInitializer.SQLITE_PLATFORM, DBInitializer.DB_PATH))
            return db.Table<Transaction>().ToList();
    }
```

**UPD2:** Пример запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE `CreatedTime` >= @Value1 AND  CreatedTime <= @Value2 AND `Tags` in {"Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"}...
```

В конце где инструкция `IN` у нас есть `List` или массив который как то туда нужно вставить, количество элементов заранее неизвестно. Ну и надо учитывать что этих параметров может и не быть.

Насчет Linq - в принципе по условиям можно пройтись с `if` и для каждого повторно отфильтровать список (хотя этот вариант напоминает `костыль`) но что делать с массивом?

Comment: А как выглядит код метода с запросом сейчас?

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Вам поможет linq to sql, приведите конкретный пример, можно будет ответить более конректно.

Comment: @koks_rs дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static List<Transaction> Transactions(string start, string end, List<string> filterTags)
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DBInitializer.SQLITE_PLATFORM, DBInitializer.DB_PATH))
        {
            var query = db.Table<Transaction>();

            if(filterTags.Count> 0)
                 query = query.Where(u => filterTags.Contains(u.Tags));

            query = query.Where(u => u.CreatedTime > start);
            query = query.Where(u => u.CreatedTime < end);

            return query.ToList();

        }
    }
```

В данном примере вы строите sql запрос и выполнятете его лишь в `query.ToList();`, то есть linq сделает всего лишь один запрос к БД вместо, как могло показаться, трех.

Comment: Это вполне может сработать ))